# Object doesn't support this property or method in ie8 for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an ASP application but I get this error in IE 8:

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> Line: 216
>
> Char: 8
>
> Code: 0

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
       Today = new Date;
      Annee = Today.getFullYear() - 18 ; //this is a Line 216
               PlageMois = Today.getMonth();
           Jour = Today.getDate() ;            
       //maxDate: new Date(new Date.getFullYear(), 1-1, 1),            
    $( "#datepicker_Majeur" ).datepicker({

           monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug','Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
           dayNamesMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
           dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',

       //maxDate: new Date(1993, 1-1, 1),
       maxDate: new Date(Annee, PlageMois, Jour),
       showOn: "button",
       buttonImage: "/images/img-calendar.gif",
       buttonImageOnly: true
    });
 });
```

Comment: Are the parentheses optional after `new Date`?

Comment: Give a try with "new Date()" instead of "new Date"

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, amazingly, they are.

Comment: @noboundaries: When calling a constructor function via `new`, if you have no arguments for it, the `()` are optional. Ref: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Thanks. Didn't look right without them to me!

Comment: Is the problem only in IE8?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Nor me, but years ago I "corrected" someone who'd left them off, and it was...a learning opportunity. :-)

Comment: Thanx to all for helping me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and so I suspect `Today` is a global being created via a non-JavaScript mechanism that doesn't let you assign a `Date` object to it.

You need to declare your local variables with the keyword `var`. I suspect that will resolve the problem you're having. E.g. (note the first four lines):

```
$(function() {
    var Today = new Date;
    var Annee = Today.getFullYear() - 18 ; //this is a Line 216
    var PlageMois = Today.getMonth();
    var Jour = Today.getDate() ;            
    //maxDate: new Date(new Date.getFullYear(), 1-1, 1),            
    $( "#datepicker_Majeur" ).datepicker({

        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug','Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Su','Mo','Tu','We','Th','Fr','Sa'],
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',

        //maxDate: new Date(1993, 1-1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(Annee, PlageMois, Jour),
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/images/img-calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is for variables to start with a lower-case letter (`today` rather than `Today`). Starting something with an upper-case character (`Today`) is usually only done for *constructor functions* (like `Date`).

Comment: another side note, to avoid clashing with implicit globals, it's better to avoid using single word, use something like `date_today` instead.

Comment: I understand your point, but if this is the case wouldn't it happen for all browsers? (Reason for comment: mention of *IE8* in the title)

Comment: @Harry: Not necessarily, no. When creating globals because of non-JavaScript things (markup, plugins, etc.), browsers get into the whole area of host objects, and the results vary from browser to browser.

Comment: Thanks Bro Problem solved, You Help me thanks a lot bro, God Blessing you